# How do I remove old computers from my iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud

Last year I was at a job where I logged into my iCloud at work.  I set my computer up with my iCloud so that everything would be hooked to my phone as well.  Long story short, I am not at that job anymore and my boss is still using that computer and I can see all of the things he's bookmarked since then on Safari.  How do I go about unauthorizing or removing that computer from my iCloud so I don't see his stuff and he doesn't see mine?

Answer (score 1):

You can log into your account on iCloud.com, select Settings and disconnect from all browsers from there. It might also be advisable to change the password of your iCloud account (and enable two factor authentication at the same time).