# Old device visible in Find My, how do I remove it?

Tags: find-my-mac, find-my, icloud

There is an old device of mine in the Find My app that has been disconnected from the iCloud account and is no longer in my possession. This device does not show up in [my settings](https://www.icloud.com/settings/). How do I remove this device from the Find My app? The solution [mentioned here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155648/how-do-i-remove-old-computers-from-my-icloud) did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove such a device from the Find My app in macOS:

1. Launch the Find My app on your Mac.
2. In the Find My app, click Devices.
3. In the Devices list, select the device you want to remove.
4. Click the Info button  on the map, then click Remove This Device. (You can also Control-click or Right-click the device in the Devices list, then choose Remove this Device at this step.)

You can find more information on this in the "[Remove a device in Find My on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/findmy-mac/remove-a-device-fmm2832fb8f0/mac)" Apple support webpage.

Comment: After a while, it reappears in the list. Is it possible that someone is using my account with the device? I was sure I put it back. I could delete it but that wouldn't be nice.

Comment: @MichaelS. Someone still using your Apple ID with your old device is the most likely explanation. If you know the person who has it, you can ask them to make sure they are logged out of your iCloud and iTunes accounts and to erase all contents and settings as described in the "[What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351)" Apple support webpage. If you don't know the person or can't reach him or her, follow the steps under the "If you no longer have your iPhone" heading on the same webpage.

Comment: It no longer appears in the list of devices, so my successor doesn't use my Apple ID either. I think it's just a bug in Find My.